# Empty Request.FILES with Django Upload forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Trying to use a very simple form to upload a file into a new class instance. I am expecting to have both files in `request.FILES` but it's empty. I am on the bundled dev server.

Been stuck here and went through all related questions.

```
wayfinder_map.media_file = request.FILES['media_file']
```

generates

> MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'media_file' not found in MultiValueDict:
>   {}>"

**model**

```
class WayfinderMap(models.Model):
    """ Way-finding Map Config"""


    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to="maps", null=True, blank=True) 
    wall_file = models.FileField(upload_to="maps_data", null=True, blank=True)
```

**view**

```
@login_required
def create_map(request, form_class=WayfinderMapForm, template_name="wayfinder/map/create.html"):
wayfinder_map_form = form_class(request.user, request.POST or None, request.FILES)

    if wayfinder_map_form.is_valid():
        wayfinder_map = wayfinder_map_form.save(commit=False)
        wayfinder_map.media_file = request.FILES['media_file']
        wayfinder_map.data_file = request.FILES['data_file']
        wayfinder_map.creator = request.user
        wayfinder_map.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(wayfinder_map.get_absolute_url())

return render_to_response(template_name, {
    "wayfinder_map_form": wayfinder_map_form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uniForm" id="wayfinder_map_form" method="POST" action="">
        <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
            {{ wayfinder_map_form|as_uni_form }}
            <div class="form_block">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create" />
                <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'create' %}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: i think the answers to this similar question will help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5895588/1037459

Comment: Besides `enctype="multipart/form"` missing, another reason can ben that the file input field doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as request.FILES is not necessary in this case (good thing cause it's empty ...)

I modified this line

```
wayfinder_map.media_file = request.FILES['media_file']
```

for

```
wayfinder_map.media_file = wayfinder_map_form.cleaned_data['media_file']
```

and it works. Not sure what the right way to do thing though... –

Answer (score 242):

old question, but somebody might still find this useful.

In order to have your `<input type=file>` files uploaded and showns in request.FILES, your form MUST contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, eg:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">{% trans 'Submit' %}</button>
</form>
```

otherwise your files will not be uploaded and your request.FILES will be empty.

**BTW** That's a common solution to a common error. Nevertheless, I still found myself in a situation with an empty FILES (and the file in the POST) when everything else was looking OK. I have the feeling it was a size limit but did not want to spend more time debugging, and just used `request.raw_post_data`. If ever somebody falls on this issue please add a comment (including precise django version!) and I'll try to debug more deeply.

Comment: @Stefano: I've fallen on this issue too. (Working with django 1.6, python 3.3) I've set encryption type and other thing, but still my request.FILES is empty.

Comment: @alireza, even thou SO is not a "support" site you might try and paste the specifics of your configuration, or a link to code if OS, otherwise it's too difficult to guess what your problem is...

Comment: when you are so much blinded by the framework, simple things like this one is always forgotten. Thank you!

Comment: jQuery Mobile also [requires](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/forms/): `data-ajax="false"`

Comment: Note that `request.raw_post_data` is now `request.body` as of 1.6

Comment: @T.Christiansen , that saved my life, i've been looking for a solution for more that two days

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was that I am missing the "name" attribute for the file input.

Comment: yes, indeed, i use my custom form, not django forms, and name attribute is required. But how i could know it?)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it is the first result on google for "django request.file empty" so I would like to add a potential solution after searching for two days:

If you submit your files through ajax, make sure to send your form via `formData()` instead of `form.serialize()`

see also here: [Django JQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822823/django-jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

I found that If you put put the form in a content block then it seems to work

```
    {% block content %}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uniForm" id="wayfinder_map_form" method="POST" action="">
        <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
            {{ wayfinder_map_form|as_uni_form }}
            <div class="form_block">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create" />
                <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'create' %}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your troubles may lie in assigning data to a form without first verifying the the request is `POST`

```
@login_required
def create_map(request, form_class=WayfinderMapForm, template_name="wayfinder/map create.html"):
  if request.method=='POST':
    wayfinder_map_form = form_class(request.user, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

    if wayfinder_map_form.is_valid():
      #save your data
      return HttpResponseRedirect(wayfinder_map.get_absolute_url())

  else:
    wayfinder_map_form=form_class(request.user)

 return render_to_response(template_name, {"wayfinder_map_form": wayfinder_map_form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: been using it this way with no problem so far. might be a good check (if necessary) but it certainly does not solve the problem as request.FILES is still empty

Comment: What do you mean 'no problems so far'? Did this work properly before?
Can you post your form class?

Comment: What I mean is that I've been using forms with no problem, as long as I don't have to use request.FILES, without checking if the method is POST. Does tying request.POST to data in the instantiation of the class like you do could help ? I'll try that and post my form.