# Dictionary: key exist or not

Tags: python, dictionary, coding-style

I use django to build my web app. And one of the page sends different files (with different file types). I have 6 file type. And my current version of code (it's really bad - that is why I write this question) is:

```
    try:
        file = request.FILES[u'file_doc']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        try:
            file = request.FILES[u'file_fb2']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            try:
                file = request.FILES[u'file_pdf']
            except MultiValueDictKeyError:
                try:
                    file = request.FILES[u'file_txt']
                except MultiValueDictKeyError:
                    try:
                        file = request.FILES[u'file_other']
                    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
                        try:
                            file = request.FILES[u'file_chm']
                        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
                            return HttpResponse('bad file type')
```

Could you advise me - how to improve this bad peace of code.

TIA!

Answer (score 6):

The `in` test let's you see if a key is part of a dictionary.

```
if u'file_doc' in request.FILES:
    file = request.FILES[u'file_doc']
```

You can simply loop through a set of keys to test for:

```
for key in (u'file_doc', u'file_fb2', .. ):
    if key in request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES[key]
        break
else:
    return HttpResponse('bad file type')
```

The `else` suite will *only* be executed if the for loop completed without reaching a `break` statement, i.e. you didn't find a matching key.

Note that you could still use your exception approach in the loop:

```
for key in (u'file_doc', u'file_fb2', .. ):
    try:
        file = request.FILES[key]
        break
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        pass
else:
    return HttpResponse('bad file type')
```

but I am not so sure that is more readable.

Comment: Or you could use a `try/except` inside the for loop.  tomato vs Tomato -- Or, in the python world, LBYL vs EAFP... (+1)

Comment: Thx! Firs time I afraid of long spaghetti-like try-except code:)

Comment: @mgilson: and that might be faster too (by a fraction), but I find the `in` test approach a little easier on the eye. Pick according to taste! :-)

Comment: If the exceptional situation is the common case (and here it is), I prefer LBYL.  On the other hand, if the file could be deleted between testing for it's existence and accessing it then EAFP would be the only way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
filetypes = [ u'file_doc', u'file_fb2', u'file_pdf' ]

file = None
for ft in filetypes:
  if ft in request.FILES:
    file = request.FILES[ft]
    break

if file is None:
  return HttpResponse('bad file type')
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to `break` out of that for-loop when you find the correct filetype?

Comment: If all three filenames are present, you'll end up with the last match.

Comment: Thx alot! It's really python-way solution:)

Comment: @Sam: Yes! I originally had a return there, but realized that didn't fit the way the OP was doing things.  Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

`request.FILES.get(u'file_doc', DEFAULT_VALUE)` will return DEFAULT_VALUE if the key does not exist in the dictionary. You can also use the `in` keyword as mentioned by Martijn
**edit** see also [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do i deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
def GetFile(request):
    file_types = "doc fb2 pdf txt other chm".split()
    for k in file_types:
        if "file_{0}".format(k) in request.FILES:
             return request.FILES["file_{0}".format(k)]
```

at least thats how I would do it