# How can I fix Django error MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django, authentication

I try to log a user but I have this error: MultiValueDictKeyError at / "'username'". I followed django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

views:

```
def home(request):

    return render_to_response('home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def login_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('start.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('home.html')
```

url:

```
 url(r'^$', 'core.views.login_user', name='login_user'),
```

html:

```
<form action="/login_user" method="POST" name="auth">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What you are following is `login_required` function. But seems you are getting different error then Give full traceback would be better to debug ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) might help you:

Use the MultiValueDict's get method. This is also present on standard dicts and is a way to fetch a value while providing a default if it does not exist.

```
username = request.POST.get("username", False)
password = request.POST.get("password", False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many errors in your code.

You are pointing your form action to `/login_user` and in your URL you don't have any `/login_user` defined so when you enter to root `/` it will load the login_user function.

I recommend you to do this:

Change your view to something like this:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usuario = request.POST['username']
            clave = request.POST['password']
            acceso = auth.authenticate(username=usuario, password=clave)
            if acceso is not None:
                if acceso.is_active:
                    login(request, acceso)                        
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
                else:
                    form = AuthenticationForm()
                    script = "alert('Usuario no activo');"
                    return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
            else:
                form = AuthenticationForm()
                script = "alert('Usuario y/o contraseña invalida');"
                return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

in your template (login.html)

```
<form action="{% url "login" %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {{ form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
</form>
```

in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'core.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^login/$', 'core.views.login_user', name='login'),
```

With this a nice form will be shown ;)