# Disable CSRF/XSRF validation in Django

Tags: python, django, csrf

I have an ASP.NET Mvc application which will send a POST request to my Django website. Now I am getting `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`. How can I disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`@csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting `MultiValueDictKeyError ` when I do `request.POST['rml']`

Comment: Thanks got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it

Comment: This error is thrown then there is no such parameter in `POST` data.  Use `request.POST.get('rml')` instead.

Comment: @warath-coder, its just a def and request.POST.get. Please try it

Comment: it works perfectly fine for me; why i ask to see your exact code; the form as well that is sending the POST data.

Comment: I am saying I have nothing special just request.POST.get('rml'). If I remove @csrf_exempt then it will work otherwise not.

Comment: id you wont post all your code (posting form and view file) there is nothing further we can do. as it works for me just fine. django 1.7.2 is my version