# Python: MultiValueDictKeyError with input array

Tags: python, django

Currently on Django and I want to do something like having an input of the same name that will hold multiple data of the same variable name. So something like:

```
<input type="text" name="material[{{material.id}}]" value="{{material.material_name}}">
```

Which will give me something like

```
<input type="text" name="material[1]" value="Mascara">
<input type="text" name="material[2]" value="Lipstick">
<input type="text" name="material[3]" value="Eyeliner">
```

And in the controller:

```
materials = request.POST['material']

for material in materials:
    material.log_material(material.keys.id, material.values.value)
```

.... something like this.

I haven't gotten that far yet but when I try to grab `request.POST['material']` I get the `MultiValueDictKeyError` error. I can do this in PHP and am new to Python and I can't really find the right equivalent to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do i deal with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

Comment: Try `print(request.POST.dict())` or `print(request.POST)` to see which keys are actually available.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the subscripts from the field names:

```
<input type="text" name="material" value="Mascara">
<input type="text" name="material" value="Lipstick">
<input type="text" name="material" value="Eyeliner">
```

And in your view, do:

```
 materials = request.POST.getlist("material")
```

Comment: I would like to add the id # in it as well.