# forms in django, overriding validation on file upload to make sure just one value is there

Tags: python, django, forms

Edit: Mostly got this working with a clean update

I added docfile2 and docfile3 beyond the example I used to code this.  I also changed the view to handle them:

```
 @login_required(login_url='/ngasite/login/')
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for fieldname in ('docfile', 'docfile2', 'docfile3'):
                file = form.cleaned_data[fieldname]
                if file:
                    Document(docfile=file).save()


            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ngasite:list', args=""))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(documents, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        docs = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        docs = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        docs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'ngasite/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'docs':docs},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
This worked pretty well, I can
```

handle three files on my form now instead of one.  But relisting after a post gives me an `attribute has no file associated with it`  error.  I am guessing because my checks for saving in the view is not really working correctly and saving regardless if there was a file or not.  Maybe my python syntax is bad?
no errors int he console though.

This is what is failing in my list.html template:

```
  {% if docs %}
                                    <ul>
                                    {% for doc in docs %}
                                        <li><a href="{{ doc.docfile.url }}">{{ doc.docfile.name }} </a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}

                                    </ul>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p>No documents.</p>
                                {% endif %}
```

So my real forms.py with the overriding of the is_valid

```
    from django import forms

 class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 7 Gigabytes',
        required=False
    )
    docfile2 = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 7 Gigabytes',
        required=False
    )
    docfile3 = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 7 Gigabytes',
        required=False
    )
    def clean(self):
        data = super(DocumentForm, self).clean()

        if not (data['docfile'] or data['docfile2'] or data['docfile3']):
            return ValidationError('You must upload at least one file.')

        return data
```

What am i missing?  my view fails on lines like

docfile=request.FILES['docfile'] cause it knows its missing, I thought my if newdoc2: etc would handle that but it doesnt work like I think it does/should

Ultimately as I learn more python and Django i want to turn this into a nice file uploader with responses to the browser to show the upload progress etc.

Comment: As I said in the [very similar question that was posted just before yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171746/django-file-field-update-causing-error-even-though-not-required/37172593#37172593) you should be using `form.cleaned_data['docfile2']` etc which avoids the problem completely.

Comment: didn't see that question as I was typing this one.  I see the cleaned data and even tried to get that to work.  Keeps saying the attribute doesn't exist, but I did notice your other post where you said cleaned_data doesnt get created until is_valid is ran.  So i do run that on the parent class(and then just return true anyway)...still says no attribute.  I am not doing a double form instantiation either like the other person you helped.

Comment: the other one on the cleaned_data no attribute is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308527/django-model-form-object-has-no-attribute-cleaned-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your fields to `required=False`, which will avoid a validation error if any field is empty:

```
docfile3 = forms.FileField(
    label='Select a file',
    help_text='max. 7 Gigabytes',
    required=False
)
```

Then in your form clean method check to see if at least one file is there:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    data = super(DocumentForm, self).clean()

    # if there are already form errors, don't proceed with additional
    # validation because it may depend on fields which didn't validate.
    if self.errors:
        return data

    if not (data['docfile1'] or data['docfile2'] or data['docfile3']):
        return ValidationError('You must upload at least one file.')

    return data
```

I have not actually run this code so there may be some little issue but you get the idea...

In your view form_valid() method, there are problems with your saving code.  Do something more like this:

```
for fieldname in ('docfile', 'docfile2', 'docfile3'):
    file = form.cleaned_data.get(fieldname, None)
    if file:
        Document(docfile = file).save()
```

Comment: that worked, or at least got me farther.  It seems my code  `docfile = form.cleaned_data['docfile']
            newdoc = Document(docfile = docfile)
            if newdoc:
                newdoc.save()`  fails as I get an error after the files are uploaded and when the view tries to list them that the docfile attribute has no file associated with it (in my template.html) < a href="{{ doc.docfile.url}}">  I am guessing because its saving what it shouldn't be.  So close

Comment: The problem with your saving code is that you are constructing a new Document object without first checking to see if there is a value for the file.  I updated my answer

Comment: updated, and it works!  i did have to change my:                 file = form.cleaned_data[fieldname] from the request.FILES as it still needed the cleaned data.  but now it works with one or more files.  Though if i select no files, it does fail on the same line with a `sequence index must be integer, not 'str'` guessing I need a cast, or something with that for fieldname to know its blank.

Comment: Cool that's great I'll fix my answer for future searchers.  As far as the other problem I don't have enough info to fix it...

Comment: yah its a tough one, i am not python-pro enough to figure it out yet.  something about that not liking `file = form.cleaned_data[fieldname]` when nothing is uploaded.

Comment: Try `file = form.cleaned_data.get(fieldname, None)`.. the `None` is the default if `fieldname` is not found in cleaned_data, which it will return instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111773/discussion-between-codejoy-and-little-birdie).