# MultiValueDictKeyError in django if condition

Tags: python, django

I have if condition in django view. In this,  if condition first checks if variable is set/not empty and in second condition it checks the value in this variable.

```
if ( request.GET['customActionType'] != '' and request.GET['customActionType'] == 'group_action') :
    records['customActionStatus'] = 'OK'
    records['customActionMessage'] = 'Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!'
```

But when I am using these variables in if condition its giving me error.

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/help
"'customActionType'"
```

Comment: I think it is duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5895670/6709516)

Comment: sorry did not get it

Comment: What do you see when you `print request.GET`? I think there is no key named `customActionType` in it.

Comment: @ozgur I think yes, thats why first i have to check if variable is isset or not how can i replace not empty condition with isset condition

Comment: sorry i ah using isset keyword because i an php developer but recently i have started working in python

Comment: Print request.data and see from Front End side you have pass the parameter in GET method only OR Print request.GET and check is there key with name 'customActionType' may be you have not pass the same key in request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments your question is duplicate of [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do i deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

But there are some improvements that can be done to your code

Change your code to

```
if request.GET.get('customActionType', '') == 'group_action':
    records['customActionStatus'] = 'OK'
    records['customActionMessage'] = 'Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!'
```

This way you won't have to do 2 checks

Comment: Great its working now