# MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/ "u'username'"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a web api for a login page. I keep getting this error. Although i have seen similar and related issues online, the solutions have been of help to me. What am i not doing right?

**error**

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/
"u'username'"
```

**login**

```
@csrf_exempt
    def my_view(request):
         user = request.POST['username']
         passcode = request.POST['password']
         user = authenticate(request, username=user, password = passcode)
         if user is not None:
             login(request, user)
             return HttpResponse("User logged in")

         else:
             return HttpResponse("User not found")
```

**updated login**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST['username']
        passcode = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=user, password = passcode)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("User logged in")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("User not found")
```

Comment: Is it a flaw in the doc?

Comment: Which doc? It means that you don't have an argument named `username` in the post body. I would suggest you to check your postman configuration.

Comment: i do have  username and password in the body already :)

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) will help you

Comment: @MohammedYasin How exactly would that help resolving the OP's problem?

Comment: @Amateur I would triple check. And post full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the request parameter from authenticate function,

```
user = authenticate (username=username, password=passcode)
```

Edit your view,

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
     user = request.POST.get('username')
     password = request.POST.get('password')
     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
     if user is not None:
         login(request, user)
         return HttpResponse("User logged in")
     else:
         return HttpResponse("User not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use the **`request.POST.get('your field_name here')`**

for example use `username = request.POST.get('username')` to pick your username