# Django - difficulty in image upload using forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to upload an image from django forms and process it using OpenCV. Here is the code I've written with the help of [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/):

1.forms.py:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

2.views.py:

```
def upload_file(request):
    context = {'status':'not working'}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            context['status'] = 'working'
            process(request.FILES['test_01.png'])
            return render(request,'create.html',context)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

Here `process()` is the function which processes the uploaded image.Running this code gives me `MultiValueDictKey Error` on the line where I call `process()`

After searching for the error, referring to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) I changed  `process(request.FILES['test_01.png'])` to `process(request.FILES.get('test_01.png'))` I get `Attribute Error` on the same line(which I guess is because I'm not able to retrieve the uploaded image properly)

Where am I going wrong and what is the correct way of doing so?

Comment: what is the type of `request.FILES['test_01.ping']`?

Comment: ok so while checking the type of `request.FILES['test_01.png']` I get the same `MultiValueDictKey Error` and the type of `request.FILES.get('test_01.png')` is `NoneType`

Comment: have you tried printing out the variable using the pprint library to see what is in the dictionary? it looks like MultiValueDictKey is Django specific

Comment: Even after using pprint I get the same error for `request.FILES['test_01.png']` and for `request.FILES.get('test_01.png')` it prints two `None` objects