# Convert javascript array into json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a javascript array

```
var arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]
```

I want to convert it into JSON array to be sent over to server like this

```
{
  "JSONarray": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]
}
```

Directly putting javascript array varible into the value doesn't help.

Tried `JSON.stringify()` it converts the whole array into one giant string.

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: you are sets only value but not property

Comment: {
  "JSONarray": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]
}
 u want to make this ?

Comment: Can u specify the error from the server side please it will be easy other wise ure question is not that understandable

Comment: @Ayeshmantha Perera it says "MultiValueDictKeyError"

Comment: Suppose ure using a python based server ?

Comment: If so go through this it's niot about ure json object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, [**JSON**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#No_really_what_is_JSON) *is* a string and *not* an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. The constructed output in the example is colloquially referred to as a **POJO** or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avaScript **O**bject. They are different. :)

> JSON exists as a string — useful when you want to transmit data across a network. It needs to be converted to a native JavaScript object when you want to access the data. This is not a big issue —  JavaScript provides a global JSON object that has methods available for converting between the two. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

The approach for sending JSON in JavaScript is to use the builtin `JSON` object's `stringify` method as you have already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the data into a string. 
This makes it simple when transferring data.

When you or someone receives this string of data, you can convert it to 'json' with
`JSON.parse()`

```
var JSONarray = JSON.stringify(arr)
// => "["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"]"
JSON.parse(JSONarray)
// => (5) ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]
```