# How to read Django template input values in Django views

Tags: python, django, textarea

I failed to get the values of textarea in django, i pasted html code below.

```
<textarea id='msg' name='message' class='form-control' rows=10 cols=30/>

<textarea id='msg' name='message' class='form-control' rows=10 cols=30/>
```

Comment: can you show ur views.py code

Comment: You said you can not read it? I'm not sure where in your view you are using this `message = request.post['message'] ` , so in general if you want it for a query set then use `message = request.GET.get['message'] ` or if you want it for saving in database, use `message = request.POST.get['message'] `

Comment: message type is textarea type before reading the message i am reading To, subject text field values as request.POST['TO'], request.POST['subject'] these two are <input type='text'> type fields these are not throwing error problem is textarea type

Comment: @srinivas so do you have multiple textarea with same name parameter?

Comment: Thank you, Mr @Khamidulla I found the problem yes I have multiple text area with the same name.

Comment: @srinivas I updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thank You, Mr @Khamidulla it's working now

Answer (score 1):

You should get your variable as follows if it is POST request:

```
request.POST.getlist('message[]')
```

Read documenation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
request.POST.get('message', None)
```

You also can find here reference here: [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do I deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
request.POST.getlist('message')
```

where  message is the name of your html attribute.