# Django doesn't read form

Tags: python, django

I have form:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact__form" method="POST" action="{% url 'backcall' %}">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <span class="text-color">Send letter</span>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone (+380)"  pattern="[\+][3][8][0]\d{9}" minlength="13" maxlength="13" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-2 mb-4">
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Your letter"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-main" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def backcall(request):
    backcall = BackCall(name = request.POST['name'], phone = request.POST['phone'], email=request.POST['email'] , message = request.POST['message'])
    backcall.save()
    return redirect('thanks')
```

models.py

```
class BackCall(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(default=None)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I fill out the form and submit nothing happens. When I follow the link 'backcall/' I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIDOH.png).

What the problem can be connected with and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, search more, exist the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

> Use the MultiValueDict's `get` method. This is also present on
>   standard dicts and is a way to fetch a value while providing a default
>   if it does not exist.

```
def backcall(request):
    backcall = BackCall(name = request.POST.get('name'), phone = request.POST.get('phone'), email=request.POST.get('email') , message = request.POST.get('message'))
    backcall.save()
    return redirect('thanks')
```

You should check whether or not the record exists in your database, I think, a quick example would be:

```
 def backcall(request):
     obj, created = BackCall.objects.get_or_create(email=request.POST.get('email'),
                           defaults={'phone': request.POST.get('phone'),
                                              'name': request.POST.get('name'),
                                              'message': request.POST.get('message')}

    if created:
       return redirect('thanks')

    return ...
```

Comment: @lozk i updated the answer, this is some best practices

Comment: same error again: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: when i changed ''[]" to "()", now it's look like this for example: "request.POST.get('phone')" i got this error: DETAIL: The error string contains (7, null, null, 2019-12-20 07:26: 23.948613 + 00, null, null).

Comment: @lozk Sorry, it was a mistake. I updated. The detail error you comment is for the data types of the model, where is the email data? You have a EmailField

Comment: why it doesn't want to fetch data from fields and save them?

Comment: Where is the email in your submit post test? (7, null, null, 2019-12-20 07:26: 23.948613 + 00, null, null)

Comment: idk, may be fifth