# MultiValueDictKeyError at /savepost/

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, django-errors

I know this has been asked before but I'm facing this MultiValueDictKeyError. Basically I'm trying to take an input from the user, the input tag has this name="usercaption" attribute. While I click on submit it pops up the MultiValueDictKeyError. Here's my HTML form:

```
<div class="post">
    <form action="/savepost/" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="usercaption" placeholder="Write Something...">
        <div class="attach">
            <button class="upload-image"><i class="fal fa-image"></i> Image</button>
            <button><i class="fal fa-video"></i> Video</button>
            <button><i class="fal fa-smile-beam"></i> Mood</button>
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's my view function:

```
def savepost(request):
    caption = request.GET["usercaption"]
    Post = post(caption=caption)
    Post.save()
    return redirect('usersfeed')
```

The error is on this line `caption = request.GET["usercaption"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do I deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a default value for if it doesn't exist, so for example:

```
 caption = request.GET.get["usercaption", ""]
```

And you have to add the user as well:

```
user = request.user
Post = post(caption=caption, user=user)
```

Comment: Im still facing the same issue  caption = request.GET["usercaption", "Write Something.."] with this code

Comment: You have a `GET` request. You should change it to `request.GET.get`

Comment: Now it gets me an Integrity Error when I type this caption = request.GET.get("usercaption", "Write Something..")

Comment: IntegrityError at /savepost/

NOT NULL constraint failed: social_media_app_post.user_id

This is what Im facing

Comment: This means that you have to add the user as well. You didn't post your model, so I didn't know. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I didn't add any input for user field though

Comment: But the user is in your `Post` model? It means you must add the field, otherwise how will it know to which user to save it to?

Comment: oh yeah that makes sense! Thanks man! It just worked! :D