# form post getting 403 forbidden error while using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, csrf-token

```
<form  action="{% url 'create'%}" method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
```

this in my template file.

```
def create(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.GET["title"]
        des = request.GET["description"]
        bid = request.GET["startingBid"]
        imageurl= request.GET[ "imageUrl"]
        category = request.GET["category"]
        image = request.GET["image"]
        listing= Auctionlisting(request,title=title,description=des,startingBid=bid,imageUrl=imageurl,category=category)
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listing":Auctionlisting.objects.all()
        })
```

and this is in my views.py.
still after using csrf token i am getting 403 forbidden error. please some guide me.
Also these title, description and all are my inputs...

Comment: this if statment will never be evaluated, everything after `return` is lost. Did you check your consoles for errors (js and terminal)? do you go to the right function/url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-arrange your code like this:

```py
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.GET["title"]
        des = request.GET["description"]
        bid = request.GET["startingBid"]
        imageurl= request.GET[ "imageUrl"]
        category = request.GET["category"]
        image = request.GET["image"]
        listing= Auctionlisting(request,title=title,description=des,startingBid=bid,imageUrl=imageurl,category=category)
        listing.save() # save before getting them from database
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listing":Auctionlisting.objects.all()
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html")
```

Comment: you probably also need to change all your `request.GET` to `request.POST`.
For MultiValueDictKeyError you need to give more explaination about what you are sending in POST request and your model. But hope this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it. (answering about his MultiValuedDictKeyError that he mentioned in an answer)