# Django Error - MultiValueDictKeyError at /new_bid/5 'total_bid.' (Beginner help appreciated)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm creating a page on a site to allow users to 'bid' on items similar to ebay. When I try to enter a number (dollar amount) on the item on the site (to enter a bid) I get the error: MultiValueDictKeyError at /new_bid/5
'total_bid.'

The problem seems to be total_bid = request.POST["total_bid"]  and I think the system believes it's None. I'm not sure why it thinks it's None because when entering the bid on the site, a number really is in the box, so if I type 100 meaning $100 bid, maybe the code is not actually taking in that number? So on POST it thinks there is nothing there?

I also tried total_bid = request.POST.get["total_bid"] with the .get part and also received an error.

I also tried adding something like "if total_bid is not none:" but I'm not sure how to do that with the syntax because I would need to declare total_bid = to something first.

I'm new to Django so additional information on how this works would be so helpful. I've already read a lot of posts on this site about this and similar errors but I'm having some trouble understanding.

views.py

```
def new_bid(request, listingid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auction_to_add = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
        total_bid = request.POST["total_bid"]
        bid = Bid.objects.create(user=request.user, listingid=auction_to_add, bid=total_bid)
        auction_to_add.bids.add(bid)
        auction_to_add.last_bid = bid
        auction_to_add.save()
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "id": listingid,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "id": listingid,
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer, which you've obviously looked at can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) and it is as you said by using `.get` which does not raise an `Exception`.

What you are doing wrong at `request.POST.get["total_bid"]` is you are using `[]` instead of `()` which is invalid. **You need to use** `request.POST.get("total_bid")` because `get` is a method not a dictionary (or anything that can be accessed in a similar way).