# MultiValueDictKeyError when trying to send an image from react-native to django

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, image, error-handling

I am building my first react-native app with a Django backend. In order for my app to work properly, I need to upload an image from react-native to Django and then save it to a model. But when I try to send the image, I get "raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'profileImage'."

here's my code:
frontend

```
const [ sentI, setSentI ] = useState(null)

const sendI = (image) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    image_data = {
      uri : image.uri,
      name : "profileImage",
      type : 'image/jpg'
    }
    if (image != null){
      formData.append( 'profileImage', image_data,)
      setSentI(formData)
      console.log('recieved')
    }
    console.log(formData)
  }


  const showImagePicker = async () => {
    
    // Ask the user for the permission to access the media library 
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your photos!");
      return;
    }
    
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    // Explore the result
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      await setProfileImage(result);
      console.log(result.uri);
      sendI(result);
      
    }
  }

const image = () => {
    


    fetch(`http://192.168.5.234:8000/home/imagetest/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        sentI
      }, 
  })
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( res => {
    console.log(res)

  })
  .catch( error => console.log(error))

}

return (
    <View style={styles.scroll}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
      <Button onPress={showImagePicker} title="Select an image" />

      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {
          profileImage !== null ? <Image
            source={{ uri: profileImage.uri }}
            style={styles.image}   
          />  
          :
          <Image style={styles.image}
            source={require('../assets/emptyProfile.png')}
          />

        }


      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
)
```

here's my backend-

```
@csrf_exempt
def imagetest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.POST['profileImage']
        print(image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that there is no keyword `profileImage` in the `request.POST` dictionary-like object.

In your javascript `image`-function, you send the object literal instead of the object `formData` itself.
Try changing it to:

```js
    fetch(`http://192.168.5.234:8000/home/imagetest/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: sentI,
    })
```

I would also suggest you try to use `request.POST.get("profileImage", False)` in Django, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5895670/6383431

Comment: I don't get the error anymore but when I try to print the image in python it gives False.