# How to get data from select from frontend Django

Tags: python, django

I have ListView and select with options in my Django template and i want to get value from select in my listview to change response by this data but i got None when i try to print that

How am i suppose to do that?

views.py

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        url = config('REPORT_PROJECT_BUDGET')

        select_front = self.request.GET.get('selection')

        payload = {'ObjectGUID': select_front, }

        print(payload)
        # response = requests.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH, params=payload).json()

        # print(response)

        queryset = []

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['OBJECTS'] = ObjectList.objects.all()
        return context
```

template.html

```
<div class="select">
    <select id="g1" name="selection">
        {% for obj in OBJECTS %}
            <option value="{{ obj }}">{{ obj }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the **name** attribute to your select element, your template should be like this,

```
<select name='selection'>
    {% for obj in OBJECTS %}
    <option value="{{ obj.pk }}">{{ obj }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah i forgot that but i already changed my question but this solution still has None

Comment: you can do it like this

select_front = self.request.GET.get('selection', 1)

and make sure that you get the value in selection otherwise it will take 1 and remove the last option tag from the select element.

Comment: I got an json error when trying to put this params into my response requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: can you take a screenshot and show it here so I can check and guide you properly?

Comment: The main problem is that value from select not sending dynamically info into my get_queryset function and i dont know how to fix that

Comment: check my answer I have updated it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select_front = request.GET['selection']
```

'selection' is name of your dropdown select

Comment: I got an error "django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'selection' " when i use this method

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5895652/9903641

first check your 'selection' is in request.GET
if your 'selection' is not exists, maybe your input isn't getting sent to Django