# Internal Server Error: MultiValueDictKeyError in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, internal-server-error

I have problem with my ecommerce project. When i try to add item to the cart I get this error.
But item is in the cart and I get this problem only in my console.
Can you please help me get rid of this error?

html code -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCns9.png

```
{% for p in products %}
                        <div class="bg-white h-[400] w-[400]">

                            <div class=" flex bg-color1 text-sm text-white absolute p-2 m-4 rounded-full ">New</div>
                            <img class="w-4/5 flex mx-auto mt-2" src={{ p.image.url }} alt="">
                            <p class=" my-2 text-center text-sm">{{ p.category }}</p>
                            <a href={% url 'core:product-detail' p.pid %} class="my-2 flex items-center justify-center text-color1 font-medium text-xl">{{ p.title }}</a>

                            <div class="flex justify-center text-center mb-2">
                                <span class="shop__price">{{ p.price }} Kč</span>
                                <span class="text-sm line-through font-sm ml-2 text-color2">29.99 Kč</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="add-cart flex justify-center text-center mb-2 ">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ p.id }}" class="product-id-{{ p.id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ p.title }}" class="product-title-{{ p.id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ p.image.url }}" class="product-image-{{ p.id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ p.price }}" class="product-price-{{ p.id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ p.pid }}" class="product-pid-{{ p.id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="1" class="product-qt-{{ p.id }}">

                                <button class="add-to-cart-btn flex justify-center text-center mb-2" data-index="{{ p.id }}">
                                    <a type="submit" id="add_to_cart" class="pointer inline-block bg-color1 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-medium transition hover:bg-color2 button">Add To Cart</a>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

js code -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NE7L.png

```
$("#add_to_cart, .add-to-cart-btn").on("click", function(){
  let this_val = $(this)
  let index = this_val.attr('data-index')
  let product_qt = $(".product-qt-" + index).val()
  let product_title = $(".product-title-" + index).val()
  let product_id = $(".product-id-" + index).val()
  let product_price = $(".product-price-" + index).val()
  let product_image = $(".product-image-" + index).val()
  let product_pid = $(".product-pid-" + index).val()
  
   $.ajax({
    url: '/add-to-cart',
    data: {
      'id': product_id,
      'pid': product_pid,
      'qt' : product_qt,
      'title' : product_title,
      'price' : product_price,
      'image' : product_image,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
      console.log("addind the product")
    },
    success:function(response){
      console.log("product added")
      $(".cart-items-count").text(response.totalcartitems) 
    }
  })
})
```

view / function -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mja5v.png

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    cart_product = {}

    cart_product[str(request.GET["id"])] = {
        'title':request.GET['title'],
        'qt':request.GET['qt'],
        'price':request.GET['price'],
        'image':request.GET['image'],
        'pid':request.GET['pid'],
    }

    if 'cart_data_obj' in request.session:
        if str(request.GET["id"]) in request.session['cart_data_obj']:

            cart_data = request.session['cart_data_obj']
            cart_data[str(request.GET['id'])]['qt'] = int(cart_product[str(request.GET["id"])]['qt'])
            cart_data.update(cart_data)
            request.session['cart_data_obj'] = cart_data
        else:
            cart_data = request.session['cart_data_obj']
            cart_data.update(cart_product)
            request.session['cart_data_obj'] = cart_data
    else:
        request.session['cart_data_obj'] = cart_product

    return JsonResponse({"data":request.session['cart_data_obj'], 'totalcartitems': len(request.session['cart_data_obj']) })
```

VScode/ console -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufFg.png

browser/ console -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcwMm.png

error detail -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEV1Y.png

Comment: Please include textual code over screen shots. Please update the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django MultiValueDictKeyError error, how do I deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.